# ошибка в подсчете калькулятора

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

почему, если первым передвинуть скролл месяца на значение 2 то сумма не меняется? а если вернуть в положение 1 то меняется, как будто стоит 2? и такая же ситуация со скроллом цена

```js
$(function () {

 function calcSumm() {
  var cash = +$("#slider-range-max-cash").slider("value");
  var months = +$("#slider-range-max-month").slider("value");
  var summ = cash * (13 / 100) * months;
  $(".summ").html(summ.toFixed(2));
 }

 $(".cash #slider-range-max-cash").slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1000,
  max: 500000,
  value: 1000,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
   $(".cash #amount").val(ui.value);
   calcSumm();
  }
 });
 $(".cash #amount").val($("#slider-range-max-cash").slider("value"));

 $(".month #slider-range-max-month").slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1,
  max: 12,
  value: 1,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
   $(".month #month").val(ui.value);
   calcSumm();
  }
 });
 $(".month #month").val($("#slider-range-max-month").slider("value"));
  
 calcSumm();

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.cash,
.month {
  width: 50%;
}

#amount,
#month {
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div class="cash">
  <label for="amount">Price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">в‚Ѕ
  
  <div id="slider-range-max-cash"></div>

</div>

<br>

 <div class="month">
  <label for="month">Month:</label>
  <input type="text" id="month" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">месяцев
  
  <div id="slider-range-max-month"></div>

</div>


<br>

<div>Сумма: <span class="summ"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide

> The value provided in the event as `ui.value` represents the value that
>   the handle **will have** as a result of the current movement.
>
> Значение `ui.value` - это значение, которое контрол **будет иметь**
>   *(но еще не имеет)* в результате текущего перемещения.

То есть Вы рано пытаетесь получить значение того слайдера, который в данный момент перемещается.

Используйте событие `change`:

```js
$(function() {

  function calcSumm() {
    var cash = $("#slider-range-max-cash").slider("value");
    var months = $("#slider-range-max-month").slider("value");
    var summ = cash * (13 / 100) * months;
    $(".summ").html(summ.toFixed(2));
  }

  $(".cash #slider-range-max-cash").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 1000,
    max: 500000,
    value: 1000,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $(".cash #amount").val(ui.value);
      calcSumm();
    }
  });
  $(".cash #amount").val($("#slider-range-max-cash").slider("value"));

  $(".month #slider-range-max-month").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 12,
    value: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $(".month #month").val(ui.value);
      calcSumm();
    }
  });
  $(".month #month").val($("#slider-range-max-month").slider("value"));

  calcSumm();

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.cash,
.month {
  width: 50%;
}

#amount,
#month {
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="cash">
  <label for="amount">Price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">в‚Ѕ

  <div id="slider-range-max-cash"></div>

</div>

<br>

<div class="month">
  <label for="month">Month:</label>
  <input type="text" id="month" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">месяцев

  <div id="slider-range-max-month"></div>

</div>


<br>

<div>Сумма: <span class="summ"></span></div>
```

Comment: а чо изменилось в вашем примере не подскажите? не могу найти

Comment: @murfuc события `slide` изменились на `change`